# Domain of validity for the asymptotic expansion of the Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions

A very short question here... I'd like to use an asymptotic approximation of a Bessel functions, which I've found given in several places as $J_\nu(z)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}cos(z-\frac{1}{2}\nu \pi -\frac{\pi}{4})$ for $|arg(z)|<\pi$ for large z.

My question is, doesn't this mean that the asymptotic form is valid for all nonnegative arguments z, since $|arg(z)|<\pi$ means $-\pi<arg(z)<\pi$? Am I misunderstanding the references' conditions or is that all there is to it?

I don't know how to derive such an expansion myself, so I don't know where the condition came from. Is it correct that the asymptotic expression is valid for all large z away from the negative real line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From its expansion, 
$$J_{\nu}\left(z\right)=(\tfrac{1}{2}z)^{\nu}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{(%
\tfrac{1}{4}z^{2})^{k}}{k!\Gamma\left(\nu+k+1\right)}$$ 
is an analytic function of $z$, except for a branch point at $z=0$ when $\nu$ is not an integer (see [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2.ii)).  In this case, the given condition $\left|\operatorname{Arg}(z)\right|<\pi$ corresponds to the principal branch of $J_\nu(z)$ (cut along the negative real axis).

If $\nu$ is an integer, $J_\nu(-z)=(-1)^\nu J_\nu(z)$, which allows to find the asymptotic expansion for $z<0$.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, then it really does just mean that the expansion is valid for all z not on the negative real line, correct?

Comment: Yes, if $\nu$ is not an integer. If it is, you can find a more general expression for the expansion.